# FULL OUTER JOIN/COALESCE isn't populating properly

Tags: sql, presto, trino, mode-analytics

I have no idea why my coalesce function isn't working.

I have two tables that I'm drawing from.

Table 1 and Table 2
Table 1 price is 0. Table 2 price is 0.33. If I coalesce I should get the 33 cents.

I do a FULL OUTER JOIN on both tables. I run the following query with the coalesce in the select statement.

```
SELECT 
p.item_id, 
p.date, 
B1.price as backup_1_price,
B2.price as backup_2_price,
      , COALESCE(B1.backup_1_price, 
                B2.backup_2_price)          as coalesce_price         

FROM 
primary_prices AS p 
    FULL OUTER JOIN backup_prices_1 AS b1
      ON p.item_id = b1.item_id
    FULL OUTER JOIN backup_prices AS b2
      ON p.item_id = b2.item_id
    
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND p.item_id = '1'
```

Result when I coalesce:

| item_id | date | backup_1_price | backup_2_price | coalesce_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-28 | 0 | 0.33 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I'm not sure why my coalesce isn't working here? Thanks so much in a advance!

Comment: COALESCE returns first non-NULL.  0 is not NULL.

Comment: You could use `case when p1 =  0 then p2 else p1 end as "price"`

Comment: On a side note: You may think you are doing full outer joins here, but it's merely left outer joins, and you should change this in your query in order not to confuse the reader. You select primary_prices with item_id 1 and to these rows you left outer join the two backup prices.

Comment: Why do you want the price of 0.33 have precedence over the price of 0? Do you always want the higher price? Or is 0 supposed to mean no price stored? In that case you should use NULL, not zero, and then your `COALESCE` would work.